# Sending pandas data frame values as text / tabular format in an Outlook mail

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, email

I have a Pandas data frame (final_pd) having values as shown below:

`print(final_pd)`

OUTPUT:

```
A   B   C
2   1   5
3   2   7
```

Now, my objective is to send these numbers to a particular email id as an Outlook email text content (and not as an attachment). For example, the email should look like:

```
Hi, below are the numbers: 

A   B   C
2   1   5
3   2   7

Thanks,
my_name
```

I am new to python (using Python 3.x) so if someone could provide the code for the same then it would be wonderful. I have searched for it and found multiple links if someone wants to send Outlook mail as an attachment (excel / html) but I don't want that. I am looking for the Pandas data frame content shown in mail content itself.

Comment: I will check and let you know by tomorrow.

Comment: @HenryYik: In  "" server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) "" , if I want to send Outlook mail then what I should use ?